# Как прибавить буква к цифрам

Tags: python

```
# Необходимо написать программу, которая спрашивает у пользователя имя и его возраст. Далее выводит введённые значения и рассчитывает, какой будет возраст у пользователя через 10 и 15 лет.
name = input("Введите Имя -> ")
kiki = input("Введите возрост -> ")
Da  = kiki + 10
Net = kiki + 15
print(f"Ого через десять лет вам будет {Net}, а через пятнадцать {Da} ого! ") 
print("Вот ваши данные!")
print(name)

print(kiki)
```

Comment: `kiki = int(input("Введите возрост -> "))`

Comment: спасибо вам, очень благодарна :)

Comment: user529352 пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

```
Age = int(input('введите возраст: '))
Name = input('введите имя: ')

Age += 10
print('ого, через десять лет вам будет ' + 
str(Age) + ', а через пятнадцать ')
Age += 5

print(str(Age) + ', ого!')
print('вот ваши данные: ' + str(Age) + ', ' + 
Name + '.')
```